# How to load FRU data in the ipmisim1.emu

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I am trying to load FRU data in the ipmisim1.emu using this command in the file:

`mc_add_fru_data 0x20 0 528 file /etc/ipmi/ibm-m3.bin <offset>`

but it doesn't work because I don't know what is the offset for the FRU ID=0.

If I replace the line above for:

`mc_add_fru_data 0x20 0 528 data 0x01`

and load the FRU data from command line:

`ipmitool -I lanplus -C0 -U ipmiusr -P test -p 9001 -H localhost FRU write 0 /etc/ipmi/ibm-m3.bin`

it works with no problem, but I would like to make the change permanent.